# Error "unhashable type: 'Index'" using in pandas

Tags: python

I'm using pandas dataframe to melt function. When i try to run the scrip it's showing me "unhashable type: index". Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

i'm getting error in below line-

```
df_cns_depivot = pd.melt(df_cns, id_vars=df_cns.columns[0],value_vars=df_cns.columns[1:], value_name="Units")
```

error-

```
unhashable type: 'Index'
```

Comment: Please also provide the error message so we can see in which line the error occurs.

Comment: its not showing me the error line number.

Comment: At least try to remove lines at the end to find the calling function in error? Or run the debugger?

Comment: i'm getting error in below line-
df_cns_depivot = pd.melt(df_cns, id_vars=df_cns.columns[0],value_vars=df_cns.columns[1:], value_name="Units")